# How to properly call a coroutine from a coroutine in a subclass

Tags: python-3.6, python-asyncio

I am new to Python's async, so bear with me please...

So, I am trying to extend the functionality of a class, let's say it's defined as such:

```py
class OrigClass:

    ...

    async def another_method(self, *args):
        # Some code irrelevant to that I want to do
        ...

    async def a_method(self, *args):
        # Some heavyweight logic which I have no desire to copy
        ...
        # After all that logic, it 'passes the torch' to yet another 
        await self.another_method(*args)
```

I want to add some checks to `a_method` through subclassing, like this:

```py
class SubClass(OrigClass):

    ...

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def a_method(self, *args):
        # Some checking / mangling of args here
        ...
        # No 'heavyweight logic' done here;
        # heavyweight logic is done in OrigClass.a_method
        yield from super().a_method(*mangled_args)
```

Is this the proper way to implement what I want to do?

Comment: The `asyncio.coroutine` decorator is deprecated. Is there a reason why you are using it, and `yield from`, instead of `async def` and `await`?

Comment: @user4815162342 it's a patch to an open source project that the maintainers haven't merged, so I adapted the additional logic to a class I derived from the open source project's. I am _really_ new to Python async so I'm still a bit confused at all the new statements.